# How do I add a number format on a cell in a MS Word table created using VSTO

Tags: .net, ms-word, vsto, add-in

I am creating tables via VSTO in an MS Word 2010 add-in.  I populate the table and add in the formula cells fine, but I haven't found a way to apply the formatting to the cell.

```
Dim FormulaPercentStyle As Word.Style = doc.Styles.Add("FormulaPercentStyle")
FormulaPercentStyle.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphRight
FormulaPercentStyle.Font.Bold = True
InsertLaborTableFormula(doc, newTable, 3, "SUM(ABOVE)*100", FormulaPercentStyle)


Private Shared Sub InsertLaborTableFormula(ByVal doc As Word.Document, ByVal newTable As Word.Table, ByVal column As Integer, FormulaString As String, NewStyle As Word.Style)
    Dim rng1 As Word.Range = newTable.Cell(newTable.Rows.Count, column).Range
    rng1.Collapse()
    doc.Fields.Add(rng1, Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldExpression, FormulaString)
    newTable.Cell(newTable.Rows.Count, column).Range.Style = NewStyle
End Sub
```

What I don't see anywhere is now to apply the number format to the formula.  To do this directly in Word, you can right click on the cell, and choose Edit Field->Formula->Number Format

What I want to do is apply the format code "P1" or "0.0 %" via code.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append the number format code to the expression as follows:

```
Private Shared Sub InsertLaborTableFormula(ByVal doc As Word.Document, ByVal newTable As Word.Table, ByVal column As Integer, FormulaString As String, FormatString As String, NewStyle As Word.Style)
    Dim rng1 As Word.Range = newTable.Cell(newTable.Rows.Count, column).Range
    rng1.Collapse()
    doc.Fields.Add(rng1, Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldExpression, FormulaString & " \# """ & FormatString & """")
    newTable.Cell(newTable.Rows.Count, column).Range.Style = NewStyle
End Sub
```

If you want to display as `"0.0 %"` you would just pass that in as `FormatString`.